# php выполнение скрипта в потоке

Tags: php

Есть скрипт, который делает 50К запросов к БД - переносит данные с одного сайта на другой.

Скрипт будет выполняться один раз. Время выполнения не принципиально.

Скрипт планируется запускать на сервере, где лежит несколько сайтов.

Как его можно запустить, или что сделать,что бы сервер не упал и не повис??

Comment: перенести данные по частям

Comment: CLI и прямые руки вам в помощь.

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском. Проявите терпение, тут не платный хелпдеск. На вопрос ответит тот, кому это интересно и когда у него будет время и желание.